# AVD wont start, get stucked when lunching the emulator

Tags: android, eclipse

I trying to run my application (clear application, after "New project"), In the log in see this:

```
[2012-04-09 15:20:25 - Test] ------------------------------
[2012-04-09 15:20:25 - Test] Android Launch!
[2012-04-09 15:20:25 - Test] adb is running normally.
[2012-04-09 15:20:25 - Test] Performing test.project.TestActivity activity launch
[2012-04-09 15:20:25 - Test] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD 'myAVD'
[2012-04-09 15:20:25 - Test] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'my
```

But then I wait and nothing happen...

Comment: Try to start the AVD independently of your application via the AVD Manager. So it will just start up the emulator but not install your app. Is the output you posted from the logCat or console view?